# Why does defining URL separately cause this seemingly unrelated error?

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-worker

Webpack v5 has [built-in support for web workers](https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/), initialized in the following format:

```js
const worker = new Worker(new URL("./worker.js", import.meta.url));
```

While working on a Next.js (with webpack v5) project, I noticed that a slight variation of the above breaks down:

```js
const url = new URL("./worker.js", import.meta.url);
const worker = new Worker(url);
```

This leads to the following error on the browser console:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

which occurs because (and only when) I'm importing something in the worker file.

Here's a [minimal reproduction](https://github.com/nilaymaj/worker-url-sandbox) of the above. Instructions to run and the lines to look at are in the README.

Why does this happen? How does defining the worker URL in a separate variable change things?

EDIT: [This comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/discussions/14093#discussioncomment-1257149) on one of the discussions on webpack's GitHub repo hints at the possible cause - that the URL constructor is handled by a different webpack loader. I don't quite understand it clearly, though.

Comment: It has already been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70033104/creating-relative-urls-with-new-url-behaves-differently-when-first-param-is no answer yet unfortunately.

Comment: @Kaiido darn, how did that not turn up earlier. My case is ever-so-slightly different but on the same note, so I'll keep this question open for a mod to decide.