# Dynamically import MDX metadata in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mdx

I'm using Next.js to generate a static blog site.

I configured `@next/mdx` according to next.js documentation and static import of MDX using `import MDXArticle from "@/app/(article)/2023/test-article/page.mdx"` works fine.

Now I need to list the titles of all articles on the homepage by using metadata, which export from mdx file.

The code below works fine:

```js
async function getArticleMetadata() {
    const {metadata} = await import(`./(article)/2023/test-article/page.mdx`);
    return metadata;
}

async function HomePage() {
    const metadata = await getArticleMetadata();
    // ...
}
```

but the other one doesn't:

```js
async function getArticleMetadata(path) {
    const {metadata} = await import(path);
    return metadata;
}

async function HomePage() {
    const metadata = await getArticleMetadata(`./(article)/2023/test-article/page.mdx`);
    // ...
}
```

```
 ⨯ Error: Cannot find module './(article)/2023/test-article/page.mdx'
    at (project-root)\.next\server\app\page.js:25:11
    at async getArticleMetadata (./src/app/page.tsx:8:26)
```

The `(project-root)/src/app/(article)/2023/test-article/page.mdx`:

```
import Cover from "./cover.webp";

export const metadata = {
    title: "test article 1",
    date: "2023-01-01",
    description: "this is a test article",
    cover: Cover
}

# a test article
```

Below is the entire code I used to get article metadata. It also prompts Cannot find module 'xxxx.mdx' and I'm sure those files exist.

```js
async function getProjectRoot() {
    let current = __dirname;
    while (current !== path.resolve(current, "..")) {
        try {
            const pkg = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(path.resolve(current, "package.json"), "utf-8"));
            if (pkg.name === config.package.name) {
                return current;
            } else {
                current = path.resolve(current, "..");
            }
        } catch (e) {
            current = path.resolve(current, "..");
        }
    }
    throw new Error("Cannot find project root");
}

export const getArticleMetadata = cache(async (path: string): Promise<ArticleMetadata | void> => {
    return await import(path).then((module) => module.metadata)
        .then((metadata: ArticleMetadataExport) => {
            const slug = metadata.slug || path.replace(/(\/page)?\.mdx?/, "")
                    .toLowerCase().split("/").pop()!;
            const tags = metadata.tags || [];
            if (typeof metadata.date === "string") {
                metadata.date = new Date(metadata.date);
            }
            return {
                title: metadata.title,
                description: metadata.description,
                date: metadata.date,
                slug,
                tags,
                cover: metadata.cover!, // todo: auto generate cover
                series: metadata.series,
            };
        })
        .catch(console.error);
});

export const getAllArticleMetadata = cache(async () => {
    const PROJECT_ROOT = await getProjectRoot();
    const ARTICLE_ROOT = path.resolve(PROJECT_ROOT, "src", "app", "(article)");
    const IMPORT_PATH = path.resolve(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url), "..");
    try {
        const articleList = await glob("**/page.mdx", {cwd: ARTICLE_ROOT});
        const articleMetadata = await Promise.all(articleList.map(async (article) =>
            getArticleMetadata(path.relative(IMPORT_PATH, path.resolve(ARTICLE_ROOT, article)))));
        return articleMetadata.filter((article) => !!article) as ArticleMetadata[];
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return [];
    }
});

export async function getArticleByYear(year: string) {
    const allArticleMetadata = await getAllArticleMetadata();
    return allArticleMetadata.filter((article) => article.date.getFullYear() === parseInt(year));
}

export async function getAllYears() {
    const allArticleMetadata = await getAllArticleMetadata();
    const years = allArticleMetadata.map((article) => article.date.getFullYear());
    return Array.from(new Set(years));
}

export async function getArticleByTag(tag: string) {
    const allArticleMetadata = await getAllArticleMetadata();
    return allArticleMetadata.filter((article) => article.tags.includes(tag));
}

export async function getAllTags() {
    const allArticleMetadata = await getAllArticleMetadata();
    const tags = allArticleMetadata.flatMap((article) => article.tags);
    return Array.from(new Set(tags));
}
```

And `next.config.js`

```js
const withMDX = require("@next/mdx")();

/** @type {import("next").NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: "export",
    pageExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "mdx", "ts", "tsx"],
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
        });

        return config;
    },
    images: {
        unoptimized: true,
    },
};

module.exports = withMDX(nextConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related with `import.meta.url` which is not exist in your related function.

Briefly, should be:

```js
async function getArticleMetadata(path) {
    const {metadata} = await import(new URL(path, import.meta.url));
    return metadata;
}
```

If you discover, the directory `.next/server/static/media/` you will see the imported file, here is related with the `import.meta.url` in nextjs apps. Related reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70256885/8260998).